# Python, squeezed between indentation levels and PEP-8 width limit

Tags: python, class, nested, indentation, pep

I have written quite a long, neat Python class:

```
class Foo(object):                     |    |
      """It is long and it has to deal |    |
      with PEP8 code width requirements|    |
      which are 72 characters for      |    |
      comments and docstrings and 79   |    |
      for actual code.                 |    |
      """                              |    |
      class_parm = 12                  |    |
      pass # after several long, broken down|
           # into several pieces, but in the|
           # end *fit* lines of script, phew|
                                            ^
                                           79 characters (say)
                                       ^    
                                      72 characters (say)
```

Now, it turns out that I need this big class to be dynamically created, so that some of its static members will be different from one instance of it to another.
It a nutshell, I need to turn it into something like:

```
def make_foo(parm):                   
    class Foo(object):                 |    |
          """It is long and it has to d|al  |    
          with PEP8 code width requirem|nts |    
          which are 72 characters for  |    |    
          comments and docstrings and 7|    |    
          for actual code.             |    |    
          """                          |    |    
          class_parm = parm            |    |    
          pass # after several long, broken |own
               # into several pieces, but in|the
               # end *fit* lines of script, |hew
    return Foo                              |
                                            ^
                                           79 characters (say)
                                       ^    
                                      72 characters (say)
```

And so it will break the PEP-8 arangement. I can still pass everything in review and break down the lines into more pieces so that it'll still fit. But it is tedious and I feel like this is something I shouldn't have worry about since it doesn't have much to see with my actual *coding* activity.

What should I do? Is there a way to achieve this without needing to add another level of indentation? Like using a decorator? Or are there magical alternative ways to delimit python blocks? Special characters maybe?

I am willing to write both standard-compliant *and* easy-to-edit `*.py` files, but it sometimes is quite a puzzling goal :\

Comment: A few things: PEP-8 is a suggestion, not a hard-and-fast rule. You've over-indented the docstring in the first place according to PEP-8. The `pass` statement is unnecessary, so you can remove it and dedent the block comment.

Comment: You could set the class parameter separately to the class declaration.

Comment: @chepner This is obviously not my actual code. And the block comment is supposed to represent actual code. How far should I follow PEP-8 then? What is wrong with docstring indentation?

Comment: @PeterWood Interesting. How would I do this?

Comment: Again, PEP-8 is only a suggestion; only code to be added to the standard library is required to comply with it. The `pep8` tool itself has a command-line option to specify a maximum line length, letting *you* decide what is too long.

Comment: `Foo.class_param = 12`, although that will affect all instances of the class.

Comment: @chepner I understand this is just a suggestion. But is it not a good practise to set a limit anyway, may it be further away from column `0`? Now that there is a limit, how to deal with the fact that Python's indentation is meaningful and that it shortens free space while being nested? I feel like there is a conflict in this case :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inheritance:

```
class Foo(object): 
    """It is long and it has to deal
    with PEP8 code width requirements
    which are 72 characters for
    comments and docstrings and 79
    for actual code. 
    """                         
    class_parm = 12
    pass # after several long, broken down|
       # into several pieces, but in the|
       # end *fit* lines of script, phew|


def make_foo(parm):                   
    class Foo2(Foo):
        """Foo without indentation problems."""
        class_parm = parm
    return Foo2
```

The child class should not have indentation problems because its very small.

Comment: This is what I finally came with. It saves the class, the indentation and is much more neat to me because it really adds to the class without altering it's code. Cheers :)

Comment: It took me day to think about it. But now it seems so obvious. :)

Comment: I think of `Foo` as being an abstract class now, and `Foo2` an instanciable kid.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the docstring of a class also by directly assigning `__doc__`.

```
doc_of_foo = '''
Very long text, very long text, very long text
'''

def make_foo():
    def one_more_level_for_good_measure():
        class Foo(object):
            __doc__ = doc_of_foo

        return Foo
    return one_more_level_for_good_measure()

Foo = make_foo()

# help(Foo) → Very long text ...
```

Comment: This is useful (even though harder to read) and I didn't know about it :) But it only solves the docstring problem right?

Comment: Well, the 72 characters are a soft limit for comments and docs, not a hard limit. Actually the 79 characters for the maximum code length are a soft limit, too, and PEP-8 says it is "okay" to use up to 99 characters in a line. If in your opinion PEP-8 is too restrictive, then ignore it. :) It's meant to make things easier, not more complicated.

Comment: I kinda like this philosophy :)